# Parallelising only inner for loop

Tags: openmp, using, parallel-processing

I have a for loop which takes around 16 ms to execute and it is executed conditionally under another for loop for 500 times.

Serial code format is like this:

```
//Outer for loop
for(i=0;i<500;i++){
//read some entity
//some conditions

// some function calls
    // some nested function calls
         // inner for loop
            for (j=0;some condition;j++){
            // work on the entity read in outer for loop

             }

}
```

I want to parallelize the inner for loop. Is it possible by making use of OpenMP to reduce the time required to execute inner for loop by 40% and hence the total time required to run the serial code?

I want overall time reduction to execute the code. Paralleizing outer for loop is not possible in my case since the code is written to read only one entity at a time to work on 
it in the inner for loop.

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: 16 ms doesn't seem like a lot of work to be parallelized.

Comment: yup, absolutely right. But, the inner for loop gets executed many times. I want to reduce the overall time required for program execution.

Comment: I am trying to parallelize the intra and inter prediction in H.264 codec. Any suggestions about that?

Comment: From my experience, parallelizing something less than ~50 ms is a lost cause. You're probably better off playing with SIMD (if you aren't already).

Comment: So you are encoding video, right?

Comment: What language are you working in and what kind of data are you operating on? Can you operate on different pieces of the data in parallel or does one step depend on the result(s) of prior steps?

Comment: yes, I am encoding H.264 codec using a reference software JM 18.0 The software itself has been written serially and I need to parallelise the inter and intra prediction in that. Please help.

Comment: @FloppyDisk I am using C language. Ya, main hurdle is interdependence between the data. I am thinking of creating multiple copies of data and trying to work in parallel and then synchronize them at the end of loop.

Comment: @user1252852 The trade offs you're making are: it's cheap (space & hardware wise) to have many copies of the data and you posit the overhead of reconciling potentially disparate changes as less than the overhead of computing serially. If you have part of the data operations dependent on the result of other operations, then you have to introduce thread locking etc. What about trying to parallel process several data items with your serial processor instead of making the processor parallel?

Comment: @FloppyDisk let me tell you how it basically works. it takes into account a 4x4 matrix does some operation 9 times and it takes ~ 16ms. Later on, another 4x4 matrix will be considered, and so on. Although this new matrix will require data from previous one, still 9 independant operations will be carried out in a for loop as I mentioned above. I was trying to parallelise the same operation inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Openmp can paralellize such small tasks. i have done this once to do a 5x5 kernel filter on 30 fps video.

You should test what the best granularity is. If you divide the task in two, you have the least overhead, but you limit the paralelism. If the granularity is too high, loop ovrhead gets bigger, and you could be writing to adjacent memory locations from different cores, which ruins cache performance.

In my example above, I divided the image in scanlines, each of which was computed sequentially. This worked fine.

Comment: great! thanks. can you please elaborate a lil' bit? Is there any way to accomplish the output just by using #pragma omp sections instead of inner for loop and having multiple copies of the inner data? And this inner for loop gets executed no. of times defined by outer for loop.

Comment: Actually doing this requires knowledge of both openmp and the algo. Just sprinkling #pragmas wont do it. With what I know of video prediction, you may not need to copy any data, all threads can share the input.

Comment: so do you mean to say that duplicate copies of data won't be needed and still by making some changes, the code can be parallelized?

Comment: For the intra prediction, it takes into account a 4x4 matrix does some operation 9 times and it takes ~ 16ms. Later on, another 4x4 matrix will be considered, and so on. Although this new matrix will require data from previous one, still 9 independant operations will be carried out in a for loop as I mentioned above. I was trying to parallelise the same operation inside the for loop.

Comment: Sound vaguely familiar from H263 (yeah, I'm really that old...). But more importantly, I think you need to write some trivial OpenMP code yourself to build up your confidence level with that technology. Like, multiply all pixels in an image by 2. Then apply this experience to the H264 algo.